# ERROR: must be member of role "" PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to change owner of table.
I created table:

```
CREATE TABLE example (some columns);
```

Then I tried to change owner:

```
ALTER TABLE database.expample OWNER TO "secondary";
```

and them I got this error:

```
ERROR: must be member of role "secondary"
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you logged in as `postgres`?

Answer (score 8):

See this from the Postgresql documentation:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

> You must own the table to use ALTER TABLE. To change the schema of a
>   table, you must also have CREATE privilege on the new schema. To alter
>   the owner, you must also be a direct or indirect member of the new
>   owning role, and that role must have CREATE privilege on the table's
>   schema. (These restrictions enforce that altering the owner doesn't do
>   anything you couldn't do by dropping and recreating the table.
>   However, a superuser can alter ownership of any table anyway.)

Comment: Short version: you can't "give away" tables, you have to be a member of the destination role.